# Access to refunded in-app purchases

Tags: mac-appstore

Is it normal that refunded in-app purchases (on the Mac) can still be re-downloaded without charge?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with the App Store.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that?

Comment: @kirby123 Only behind developer program membership login—should I add the link anyway?

Comment: It might be helpful for others who have a developer account, I suppose. But it's good to know that Apple is aware of this issue.